# Why meditate. . .?

Tags: meditation

Back to basics. If asked, “why meditate,” perhaps responding with the question, “why breathe,” may get to the heart of the question?

Recalling some worthwhile answers:

— In order to properly respond when required
— So as not to miss the tiny flowers on one’s walk
— To see things as they truly and actually are

Answer (score 1):

If one were to contemplate how to get rid of birth, aging, decease and death, one might discover realizing the **Four Noble Truths** is the way and meditation is part of the methodology in such realization.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of knowledges to be gained.

1. Sutamaya Panna - knowledge gained by listening or reading
2. Cintamaya Panna - knowledge gained by analytical thinking.
3. Bhavanamaya Panna - knowledge gained by meditation

Out of these three types, only the knowledge gained by meditation is sharp enough to cut through defilements. More specifically speaking, one needs to see impermanence, suffering and non-self through direct knowledge to cut off craving. Hearing about them or logical thinking is too weak to overcome craving.